# Feedback resistance condition (Rf > 29R) in Phase-shift oscillators

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, oscillator, feedback, oscillation

In an equal resistance , equal capacitance CR   phase-shift oscillator, the feedback resistor has to be slightly larger than 29*R

When     I  am    attempting to simulate the circuit at 29*R, there's an oscillating transient response but it is not unstable, hence the circuit will reach a steady-state, however once I increase the feedback resistance slightly above 29R, the response is unstable and the phase-shift oscillator is functioning properly. why is that? shouldnt a feedback resistance of 29R be theoretically sufficient for an unstable response?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each oscillator circuit the designed loop gain has to be slighly larger than the theoretical value of "1" (oscillation condition). This is because **(a)** in most cases, the calculation of the circuits assumes no parts tolerances as well as IDEAL opamp properties (input/output impedances, infinite gain) and **(b)** a safe start of oscillations must be ensured with a pole pair slightly into the right half of the s-plane (loop gain >1). As a consequence, oscillation will safely start and amplitudes will rise continuously until an amplitude limitation will take place (supply voltage limitation or other non-linear parts like diodes) - thereby reducing the loop gain to a mean value of unity.

Answer (score 0):

That factor (29) is only true if your opamp is ideal. If it does not have 'infinite' gain at the oscillation frequency, you'll need a higher resistance.